# JSP property file read

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jsp, apache-tiles

I am making one web application. In this application i am using `maven`, `Spring framework`, `Hibernate framework`, `JSP`, `Apache tiles`.

Still this application is in English language. So now my requirement is convert application is in Portuguese language. So i create one properties file for Portuguese language and use this properties file when require.

In my application create two properties file,
1 for english language(`messages.properties`), 2 for portuguese language(`messages_pt.properties`)

In my jsp page when i fetch value from `messages.properties` file at that time working properly but when fetch from `messages_pt.propertie`s file at that time not working properly because in `messages_pt.properties` file contains some special character

see my both properties file

```
messages.properties
    gas=Gas

messages_pt.properties
    gas=Gás
```

Now come to my question...

In JSP page i am using `fmt tag library` for read value by key from properties file
my jsp page is like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        ..............
    </head>
    <body>
        ..............
        <fmt:message key="gas" />
    </body>
</html>
```

so when fetching value for `gas` key from `messages_pt.properties` file at that time getting `G�s` value.

I search solution in google and getting some solution but no one can solve my problem

I am applying below solution

1) In JSP page i add contentType in  first line and in meta tag. Please see my jsp page above.

2) I added `CharacterEncodingFilter` in `web.xml` file and this filter is in first filter from start page.

```
<filter>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
        <init-param>  
           <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
           <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <init-param>  
           <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
           <param-value>true</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

3) I added `defaultEncoding` in `messageSourceBean` in `xxx-servlet.xml` file

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:properties/messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

4) I added `project.build.sourceEncoding` in `pom.xml` file.

```
<properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     .......
</properties>
```

5) I tried below code

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> 
<p><spring:message code="label.menu"/></p>
```

But now can solve my problem.

If anybody know any other solution then please tell me.

Comment: A properties file is supposed to be encoded in ISO-8859-1. My guess is that yours is encoded in UTF8.

Comment: Thanks JB for reply.. I tried properties file encoded in 'ISO-8859-1' but i getting 'Gï¿½s' instead of 'Gás'. So any other solution you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a same issue in my past, I doing the following solution see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Go to file properties > Resource >

Change yourc content type to `UTF-8` .